# Can not print out the filename when the directory is too long by using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory

I used python to print out the filename in a certain directory. But when the directory is too long the output comes out an empty matrix.

**#This code outputs the correct filename:**

`import globpr
int glob.glob("D:\One\Two\Three\Four\*.dcm")`

The output here is the exact the filename under in the directory. However, when it get to a sub-directory beyond this, it generates an error.

**#This code generates an empty matrix:**

`import globpr
int glob.glob("D:\One\Two\Three\Four\Five\*.dcm")`

The output here is an empty matrix. Any help thank you

Any suggested help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape your backslashes. You've stumbled upon an escape sequence.

```
glob.glob('c:\\real\\path\\here\\*.dcm')
```

Comment: or, for readability, make it a raw string `r"D:\One\Two\Three\Four\Five\*.dcm"`

Comment: what do you mean escape my backslaches?

Comment: or even better use unix style seperatorsz since python understands them regardless of os, and they require no escaping ...